# Convert it to Submit Function

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-forms

How can i make this form to work on submit it function. Currently, i select the option and automatically changes the data. I want the submit button to be clicked first before the changes can happen.

```
<div class="select" >
    <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue[i]" (ngModelChange)="assignCorporationToManage($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let corporation of user_corporations" [ngValue]="corporation">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manage">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: remove that ngModelChange and add that to the submit method function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in assignCorporationToManage method you need currently selected value for that Just remove that ngModelChange and add that to the submit method function something like

```
<div class="select" >
    <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue[i]" >
        <option *ngFor="let corporation of user_corporations" [ngValue]="corporation">{{corporation.corp_name}}</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manage" (click)="assignCorporationToManage(selectedValue[i])">Submit</button>
</div>
```